# Image doesn't fit grid when the grid is minimized

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have image that have space when i look at device with resolution `sm` and `xs` how to make it fit with the grid?

here is my code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/550x350" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h2>How do you auto-resize a large image so that it will fit into a smaller width div container whilst maintaining it's width:height ratio?</h2>
    <p>How do you auto-resize a large image so that it will fit into a smaller width div container whilst maintaining it's width:height ratio?</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

from the resolution `991px to 581px` I get blank space from image (like it didn't fit to the grid)

http://www.bootply.com/10CUN9fXqG#

How do I fix it?

Comment: Like this? http://www.bootply.com/e2ML3nYVnC

Answer (score 0):

I would just add `width: 100%;` to your image

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be your solution code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/550x350" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h2>How do you auto-resize a large image so that it will fit into a smaller width div container whilst maintaining it's width:height ratio?</h2>
    <p>How do you auto-resize a large image so that it will fit into a smaller width div container whilst maintaining it's width:height ratio?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using bootstrap `classes` for `sm` and `xs` screens, use that as well as change the `img` from `max-width` to `width`.

```
 img{
    width :100%;
 }

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/550x350" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
  <h2>How do you auto-resize a large image so that it will fit into a smaller width div container whilst maintaining it's width:height ratio?</h2>
  <p>How do you auto-resize a large image so that it will fit into a smaller width div container whilst maintaining it's width:height ratio?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Try adding custom styling